# on server webservice call not working

Tags: android, web-services, cordova

I m developing app using **android-phonegap**.
its working fine when i call webservice hosted on my pc.
But when i deploy it on ssl server, i a not getting any output.
my code is :

```
function CallService() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://devpc4:5566/Service1.asmx/GetItems",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError
        });
    }
```

can any one help me?

Comment: More details, please. And, besides this: "...deploy it on ssl server..." but url: "http_://devp..." ?

Comment: "http://devpc4:5566/Service1.asmx" is url where i have deploy webservice in my local server. is it right way to write url in ajax?

Comment: yes, I only mean that you speak of an ssl server but the URL doesn't use https but http, as this this is just a test machine. But you said it only doesn't work when deployed on your SSL server so this might have to do something with it. Anyway, to debug it here you need to provide muuch more infos, and mostly we need a logcat from the android devide AND server logs.

Comment: go to this [link](http://devpc4:5566/Service1.asmx) and try to call GetItems method which does not have any parameter. and please tell me if you can do any thing. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check logs. Both on device and your server

Answer (score 1):

You have to add some headers on your server which will allow you to call web-service from other server.

I mean to say, When your web-service is hosted on one server and you are calling it from other server then your server may not allow this.

So you have to add some "header permissions" on your server